# angular js search bar, returns only data I entered into search bar

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to enter a country into a search bar, use ng-click or ng-submit to return only the data for the country i entered into the search bar.  right now when i submit, i get every country returned and then i can filter to get the country i want.  I have all my data in mongolab, i use node js to get my data to my angular js service, then i have an angular js controller that sends data to the view i want.  I am using anguler ui router.  Here is my service:

```
    angular.module('TravelSite').service('countryService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

this.getCountry = function() {
  var dfd = $q.defer();
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/country'
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      dfd.resolve(response.data);
      }, function(err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
  });
    return dfd.promise;
  };

this.addCountry = function(body) {
var dfd = $q.defer();
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/country',
    data: body
  }).then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data);
    dfd.resolve(response.data);
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('error: ' + error);
  });
    return dfd.promise;

  };

}]);
```

here is my controller:

```
    angular.module('TravelSite').controller('CtrlCountry', function($scope, countryService) {



$scope.addCountry = function(country, cb) {

    countryService.addCountry(country).then(function(res) {

    });
}

$scope.getCountry = function() {

    countryService.getCountry().then(function(dataFromService) {
        $scope.countries = dataFromService;

    });
}
```

});

here is my view:

```
       <div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="search.name">      

        <input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="country.name"/> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="population" ng-model="country.population"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="travel warning" ng-model="country.travel_warning"/>  
        <input type="text" placeholder="visa" ng-model="country.visa"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="vaccinations" ng-model="country.vaccinations"/>

        <button ng-click="addCountry(country)">Create Country</button> 
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="getCountry()">

        <input type="text" ng-model="country.name"> 

        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>




        <button ng-click="addCountry(country)">Create Country</button> 
    <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="country in countries | filter:search">{{country.name}}
         {{country.population}}  {{country.travel_warning}}  {{country.visa}}  {{country.vaccinations}}</li>
    </ul>



</div>
```

I have only been coding for about a month, if anyone can help me, i will be extremely grateful.

thanks, and sorry in advance about the terrible looking code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to Angular too. :)

I have some code that does exactly the same. I get a lot of info and, then, filter out only what I want.

Whant you can do to filter is to just do some changes on your view.
On your search input box, you can just do this:

```
<input type='text' ng-model='search'>
```

Then, on your ng-repeat, you may use:

```
<li ng-repeat="country in countries | filter: {name: search}">
```

If you want to filter all the fields, you may use this instead:

```
<li ng-repeat='country in countries | search'>
```

Hope it help. :)

Comment: thanks!, yes, it helps a lot, it is doing exactly what i want it to do now

Comment: IF it helps and your problem is solved, can you mark this answer? :)